# How to calculate percentages in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice

I am currently calculating percentages in LibreOffice Calc using the function `=PART/TOTAL` where `PART` and `TOTAL` are cell coordinates of a same column.

Dragging-down the formula won't do, because the coordinate of the `TOTAL` cell will change along with the PART's.

Ideally, I want to process this quickly, in a way that the coordinates of the `PART` changes while the `TOTAL`'s would remain the same.

How can I do that? Is there a function for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify the formula from, say, `=A1/A2` to `=A1/$A$2` before copying it, so that the denominator will not change.

Comment: Also, you can just fix the column using `$A2` or just fix the row with `A$2`. This is useful when copying between different columns/rows (depending how your data is laid out)

Answer (score 0):

To calculate percentages you can use the formula described at [Libre Office Help](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Calculating_With_Formulas):

```
=A1*16%   # Displays 16% of the contents of A1.
```